# laravel and php 5.3.23?

Tags: laravel, php-5.3

i have an assignment at my company to build a custom cms, for the foundation i ve chosen latest laravel(version 4, i believe).

Now, the requirements in laravel docs(http://laravel.com/docs/installation#server-requirements) 
say minimal version of php on server required is **5.3.7**, our servers have php **5.3.23**.

I am right now on a weekend, so i cant check my code on the server( been developing the basics on localhost with xampp which has latest php).

Has anyone tried laravel 4 on pre-5.3.7 php?? i m very worried all of last week's work is going to the bin... :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

5.3.7 < 5.3.23

PHP 5.3.23 is perfectly fine since it came out AFTER 5.3.7.

PHP 5.3.23 came out March 14th 2013, while PHP 5.3.7 came out August 18th 2011.

Comment: thanks! i thought its 7 like 70, in most version numbers, you know, then itd be newer then 23, well lucky me anyway and thanks.a lot for lifting that mountain off my shoulders :-)